# Zabbix Graph KBps to Kbps

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-custom-reports

Need to change Graph's KBps to Kbps

[image: 1]

Need to change Graph's KBps to Kbps
Using "VMware Guest" Template

Answer (score 0):

You can change the unit on the item prototype, but the item name is "Number of Bytes", so **Bps** looks correct.

> Kilobits per second is shortened to kb/s, Kbps or kbps (as opposed to
> KBps, which is Kilobytes per second

See: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.0/en/manual/config/items/itemtypes/simple_checks/vmware_keys?hl=vmware.vm.net.if.in

[image]

[image]